# 'BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING__AT_key' is not defined for Pandas Querying function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, numpy

Trying to get a hold of pd.query function

Getting an error

> UndefinedVariableError: name 'BACKTICK_QUOTED_STRING__AT_key' is not defined

for the below pandas Python code. What did I do wrong?

```
def ft_equal(df,key,value):
    # print(key)
    # print(value)
    # return df[df[key] == value]
    # print(key)
    # print(df[key])
    # return df.query('@key == "%s"' %value)
    return df.query('`@key` == @value')

pd.DataFrame.ft_equal = ft_equal

df.ft_equal("Current State","Disburse")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def ft_equal(df,key,value):
    my_query = key + " == " + value
    return df.query(my_query)
```

or

```
def ft_equal(df,key,value):
    return df.query(f"{key} == {value}")
```

Comment: amazing try at solving

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to actually substitute in the values of `key` and `value` ... you can do this with an `f` string in python3

```
(f'`@{key}` == @{value}')
```

in older python versions you would need to do

```
'`@{key}` == @{value}'.format(key=key,value=value)
```

Comment: Error persists still